# How can I create a function that will only run if a range of cells is not blank for google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I want to run a SUM function only if f6:i6 have values. This sheet is receiving input from a form and I want to apply a function to sum the values as they are put in from the form. Right now I am getting a parse error, and if I run just the sum function (no IF function included), I get an N/A error that says

```
"Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "[0-9]+" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value ""."
```

Function:

```
=IF((f6:i6 !ISBLANK),"(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(value(regexextract(F6:I6, "[0-9]+"))),J6))")
```

Comment: Try: =IF(ISBLANK(F6:I6),,sum(F6:I6))

Answer (score 0):

if you need that regexctract try this:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(1*IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(F6:I6&"", "[0-9]+"))))
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!